# Creating Word 2016 document repeating section from multiple SharePoint Online list items

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, word

I'm aware of how to include Document properties in a word template. What I'd like to achieve in addition to this, is data from another list (1 to many relationship) in a repeating section.

For example... I have a document library "Person" with columns for Name and Date of Birth. In a separate list, I have columns for Name (same as Name in Person library), Favourite Activity and Description. In template for the "Person" library, I'd like to insert their name, date of birth, and a paragraph for each of their favourite activities.

Is this doable?

As a workaround I've tried using a SPD2013 workflow to concatenate the values from the list and insert them to a single column in the People library, without much joy.

Answer (score 1):

It is not doable out of the box. We done something similar at my current job and to do that you need to develop custom office add-in. Add-in was querying Sharepoint list and populate the document using the rich text from list.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Marek! I guess I'll start on my custom Add-In